# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStack

Tags: struts2

**Struts2 with JSP**

I have a project with `Struts2`, `JSP` and `Tomcat 6.0`
I am new to `Struts2`

Getting error message in server trace when i try to check the message in JSP through Struts2 but i am not sure why i am getting this below error

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStack
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2651)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1467)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1280)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1141)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:416)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:163)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:250)
    at java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Introspector.java:397)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:163)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$TagHandlerInfo.<init>(Generator.java:3924)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.getTagHandlerInfo(Generator.java:2187)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1643)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1530)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2411)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2417)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:495)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2361)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3474)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:231)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Jars are listed below:

```
asm-3.3
asm-commons-3.3
asm-tree-3.3
struts2-api-2.0.1
struts2-convention-plugin-2.3.16.3
struts2-core-2.3.16.3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add **xwork.jar**

PS:You should use maven for dependency management