# HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/ValueStack

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, tomcat7

I am trying to integrate Struts 2 with Hibernate ORM. I have created a Maven project in eclipse. I have added all the dependencies that is required for the project. I am getting HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/ValueStack when trying to deploy and run the Application in Tomcat 7.

I have checked all the posts in this forum related to this issue wherein the resolution i found was to add the xwork-xxx.jar file. I have added the xwork2.3.4.1 jar  which is part of the dependency that comes with Struts2-core.jar. The dependency is already present in pom.xml. I am also able to see the required jars in the war file that is built in maven and deployed in tomcat server. But still i am getting the HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/ValueStack Exception.

```
List of Jars in war:

javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
struts2-core-2.3.4.1.jar
xwork-core-2.3.4.1.jar
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
asm-commons-3.3.jar
asm-tree-3.3.jar
freemarker-2.3.19.jar
ognl-3.0.5.jar
javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
commons-io-2.0.1.jar
hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar
jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar
antlr-2.7.7.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar
classmate-1.3.0.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar
```

I am not able to find out what needs to be done to resolve this issue. Any help is highly appreciated. TIA.

Below is the Exception trace.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/StrutsMavenDemo] threw exception [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/ValueStack] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStack
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Introspector.java:1336)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Introspector.java:1197)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:426)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:173)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:260)
    at java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Introspector.java:407)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:173)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:260)
    at java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Introspector.java:407)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:173)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:260)
    at java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Introspector.java:407)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:173)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$TagHandlerInfo.<init>(Generator.java:4044)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.getTagHandlerInfo(Generator.java:2289)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1717)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1553)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2392)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2444)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2450)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:474)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2392)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3591)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:251)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:660)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:364)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

POM.XML:
========
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
      <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: dude, `ClassNotFoundException`

Comment: @SimonSchnell Yes i am getting the ClassNotFoundException. It says it is not able to find the ValueStack class  but i have included the xwork2.3.4.1 jar file which has the class com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStack.Could you please let me know what could be causing the issue? TIA.

Comment: @user903676 show us the jar files included along with complete logs

Comment: are you sure you have xwork jar ?

Comment: I have updated the question with the Jar files used and the pom.xml entries. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883746/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-opensymphony-xwork2-util-valuestack)